# error: no matching function for call to my class constructor

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, compiler-errors

I have a strange error while using my new class Texture

```
#include <ImageMagick/Magick++.h>

class Texture
{
public:
    Texture(GLenum TextureTarget, const std::string& FileName);
    Texture(GLenum TextureTarget,const Magick::Image* img);
```

when I try to use it

```
Magick::Image* image_small = 
  new Magick::Image( Magick::Geometry(pCodecCtx->width/8,
                     pCodecCtx->height/8),
                     Magick::Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
/*135*/ Texture* txtr = new Texture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                    (const Magick::Image*)image_small);
```

I get

```
P.cpp|135|error: no matching function for call to ‘Texture::Texture(int, const Magick::Image*)’|
```

Comment: you don't have to specific const , Magick::Image*  would be ok in Texture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,(const Magick::Image*)image_small)

Comment: Is that the only 2 constructors you have? Do compiler report what candidate functions are?

Comment: e: candidates are:
.. note: Texture::Texture(GLenum, const string&)

Comment: Is `GL_TEXTURE_2D` a member of `GLenum`?

Comment: show the definition of `GLenum` in your project? When I [googled](https://www.opengl.org/registry/api/GL/glcorearb.h) , it said `typedef unsigned int GLenum;` , which would mean that the arguments actually do match.

Comment: If there is only one candidate, then second function probably just isn't visible to compiler at all. I suggest making minimal example reproducing a problem - i'm almost sure some essential parts of code are omitted from question; the code presented is just fine.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `GL_TEXTURE_2D`?